# Displays are offset; screen capture shows different layout; monitors are misidentified

Tags: kubuntu, display, kde, display-resolution, orientation

Kubuntu 23.04
Plasma 5.27

I've had to do this with a combination of cell phone camera and screen captures, because the screen captures are much different from reality.

The description is the title: Displays are offset; screen capture shows different layout; monitors are misidentified

I use three monitors, L-R LG, Viewsonic, HP. I recently traded out the leftmost monitor, and everything's been fine for a couple of days. All the cable connections remain the same, just the monitor changed.

When I logged in this morning, the monitor placement and layouts are screwed up: display layout is correct in the settings, but isn't accurately reflected in the monitors. I've posted about this before and ultimately had to reinstall the OS. I'd rather not do that this time.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]